# Raabe test reference request

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, reference-request

I just discovered that there is a convergence test called Raabe test

If $\displaystyle   \lim_{n \to \infty}\inf \left\{ n \left(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}-1 \right) \right\} >1  $ then the series $ \sum_{k=1 }^ \infty a_k$ is convergent and if$\displaystyle   \lim_{n \to \infty}\sup \left\{  n \left(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}-1 \right)\right\} <1$  then the series $ \sum_{k=1 }^ \infty a_k$ is divergent

I want to ask which book contains this theorem? It looks like this theorem is not in my book (Introduction to Real Analysis by Robert G. Bartle)

Comment: What about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#2._Raabe's_test ? Or https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RaabesTest.html ?

Comment: Agree with Martin, reading it on Wikipedia is a good way to learn.

Comment: @MartinR I would like to know the book that contains this theorem because it might as well contain other theorems that I have never heard of .

Comment: This [handbook](https://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/info/mathhandbook/contents.htm) can be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with the already mentioned Robert G. Bartle, Donald R. Sherbert - Introduction to Real Analysis, Fourth Edition -John Wiley & Sons, 2011, page 274 Raabe test is in following books:

1. John M.H. Olmsted - Advanced calculus-Prentice Hall, 1961, page 396
2. G.M. Fikhtengol'ts - Differential and Integral Calculus - vol. II, 2003, page 300
3. Petrovic, John Srdjan - Advanced Calculus - Theory and Practice-CRC Press, 2013, page 491
4. Angus E. Taylor, W. Robert Mann - Advanced Calculus-Wiley, 1991, page 591